states and density matrices, compactness
I just started reading about the $C^*$-algebras so I'm hoping that what I'm writing won't be awfully wrong. I had a doubt regarding the connection between states in an algebra and density operators in infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces.
Consider a generic separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and the algebra of bounded operator in $\mathcal{H},B(\mathcal{H})$.
1-A state in a unital $C^*$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is a linear map $\omega:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that $\forall a\in \mathcal{A},\omega(a^*a)\geq 0$ and $\omega(1)=1$. Call the set of states $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{A})$.
2-A density operator $\rho\in B(\mathcal{H})$ is an operator such that: $\rho\geq 0$,$\rho$ is hermitian and $\operatorname{tr}(\rho)=1$. Call $S(\mathcal{H})$ the set of density operators.
Set $\mathcal{A}=B(\mathcal{H})$.
Between the two there should be this relationship: if $\omega\in \mathcal{S}(\mathcal{A})$ is a state then there exists a $\rho\in S(\mathcal{H})$ density operator such that $\forall a \in \mathcal{A},\omega(a)=\omega_{\rho}(a)=\operatorname{tr}(\rho a)$ and vice versa if $\rho$ is a density operator then we can associate to it a state $\omega_{\rho}$.
Then we know that if $\mathcal{A}$ has a unit then the $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{A})$ is a compact convex set in the ultraweak topology.
The set $S(\mathcal{H})$ is compact for finite dimensional $\mathcal{H}$, it fails to be compact for infinite dimensional $\mathcal{H}$ in the ultraweak topology.
The question is why does this happen? I thought that basically $\mathcal{S}(B(\mathcal{H}))$ and $S(\mathcal{H})$ were isomorphic but evidently this cannot be true in every dimension. Is there something wrong in what I wrote?

It is no longer true in infinite dimensions that all states are given by density operators. If a state is given by density operator, then we call it a normal state. See for example Theorem 2.4.21. in Operator Algebras and Quantum Statistical Mechanics 1 by Bratteli and Robinson.
There is also this post on the existence of non-normal states Non normal state.
